# Terminal perform action for batch of files

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have 200 files of `.png` type placed in a folder. 
I need to perform these 2 actions to every file

```
try ls -l xyz.png 
chmod -x xyz.png
```

How can I do it without applying it manually for every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in *.png; do
    # Skip if not a regular file
    [ -f "$f" ] || continue
    ls -l "$l"
    chmod -x "$f"
done
```